# Blackberry web/widget (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, cordova

I am a new developer here.. I have several question here. Hope you  all can help me..

1, Can I convert format .cod to .jar/.jad.. if can, can you give me a link?

2, can you all give me a link to check OS  Version and phone model for Blackberry?

3, Research In Motion (RIM) must track the use of sensitive APIs noted as signed (runtime, application and cryptography APIs) when used by applications for security and export control reasons. If you use these controlled classes or methods in your applications, your application must be signed with a key or a signature provided by RIM before you can load the application .cod files onto the BlackBerry smartphone. So my question is, the phonegap need to signed key or not? FYI, write now I am using phonegap to develop application blackberry by blackberry web/widget (eclipse).

Thank you very much,

Jamaley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering under the assumption your questions are directed at PhoneGap applications, and using the PhoneGap API.

1. Yes. When you build the binaries, you get a .cod, .alx, .jar, and .jad file. See the [docs on BlackBerry's site](http://docs.blackberry.com/id-id/developers/deliverables/20957/Making_BB_Widget_apps_available_to_users_896746_11.jsp).
2. Assuming you are using PhoneGap, you have access to the `device` JavaScript namespace that will give you these properties. `device.name` returns the numerical value of the BlackBerry model (i.e. 8900, 9000, 9700, etc.). `device.version` will return the OS version string (i.e. 4.6.0.586, 5.0.0.250, etc.). See the [device docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_device_device.md.html) for more information.
3. Yes, you do need to sign your PhoneGap applications. If you want to run any type of app on the BlackBerry - Java, WebWorks, PhoneGap - you have to sign it.

Comment: hi dude, thank for your respond.

1, when I build, I just get a .cod, and .alx in folder standardInstall, In folder OtaInstall i get many .cod file like abc.cod, abc-1.cod, abc-2.cod...

2, did you mean when I write the code, I must be include the function device.name, device.version. Should I write code for all model and version. i am not really understand dude. how the app works? can you give me example?

3, how to sign my phonegap application? so you mean my app can run on different model and different os version?

thanks dude.

Comment: Jamaley, a few things. I think you need to first understand the BlackBerry development flow a bit better. It seems you are very confused. Take a look at the basic documentation on the BlackBerry developer site to become familiar with what a BlackBerry application looks like, why you need to code sign and how to do it, etc. All of this information is available on BlackBerry Developer site.